# How can I make the css background?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create static basic HTML & CSS page but I was wondering how can I make the background like the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJSG6.png) attached?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If we're going to assist you, we'll need to see your code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post your attempt so we can troubleshoot it. :)

Comment: @AStombaugh FYI, You can get the [mcve] link by typing `[mcve]`. And there are [others](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple CSS code. Add this in you `<head>`-tag.

```
<style>
body {
background-image url(image.png);
}
</style>
```

You can replace `body`. E.g.: `div#idcard` or `div.idcard`.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on aWebDesigner123's answer:

```css
body {
background-image: url(https://na-dache.pro/uploads/posts/2021-05/1620984771_105-p-greipfrut-foto-119.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

background-image: url(path); should be added to give the background image to the website.

For further syntax, you can refer the following documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image